# Additional drainspout installation

Tags: plumbing, water, repair

This gutter is overflowing during heavy rain and Id like to add an additional downspout to help, however im not sure if i should add it all the way at the far left and then adjust the gutter so it slopes from the middle down to each side, or if i should add a downspout in the middle and leave the slope alone. Any help would be appreciated
[image: back of house]
[image]

Comment: Either should work, middle with no slope change should be easier. So unless you particularly want the water on the left side...